# Laravel relationship whereRaw constraint inside with() method

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, "Employee" and "EmployeeLeaveLog". 
I'm trying to get employees record with their current month leaves records, using the code below, but it's showing me an error.

The sql code that I want to put in the whereRaw() is :

```
SELECT * FROM employee_leave_log
WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + 
INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND ( (till_date IS NULL) OR (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) <  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)));
```

And the Laravel code is :

```
Employee::with(['leaveRecord' => function($query){ 
$query->whereRaw("((UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) >= 
(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))) 
AND ( (till_date IS NULL) OR (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) <  
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY))))");
} ])->all();
```

**Edit :**

EmployeeLeaveTable has following main columns :

leave_log_id,

employee_id,

from_date,

till_date (contains Null if leave is applied for only one day.)

**Edit 2:** 
I found out a logical error in the SQL code that I was putting in the whereRaw().

The correct SQL code should be :

```
SELECT * FROM employee_leave_log
    WHERE (
              (
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
              )
              OR
              (
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
              )
          );
```

Comment: what do you mean current month leaves records ?

Comment: @Leorent leaves which have been taken in the current month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question. Finally I found the issue, there was a logical error in the SQL statement.

Following code should work :-

```
Employee::with(['leaveRecord' => function ($query) {
$query->whereRaw("(
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(from_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
              )
              OR
              (
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
                  AND
                  (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(till_date) < UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LAST_DAY(CURDATE()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY))
              )")})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get current month leaves you could do something like:

```
Employee::with(['leaveRecord' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('from_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth());
    $query->whereDate('till_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
}])->get();
```

Comment: Didn't worked.  The till_date column can be null in case if it's only one day leave.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error are you getting?

You could try this:

```
Employee::with(['leaveRecord' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('from_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
       ->whereNull('till_date')
       ->orWhereDate('till_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
}])->get();
```

Update, try this:

```
Employee::with(['leaveRecord' => function ($query) {
    $query->whereDate('from_date', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth())
        ->where(function ($query) {
            return $query->whereNull('till_date')
                ->orWhereDate('till_date', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());
        });
}])->get();
```

This should wrap the second part in `()` to fix the issue.

Comment: Not working ... The SQl generate by the query is wrong.

Comment: Here is the generated SQL       -       "select * from `employee_leave_log` where date(`from_date`) >= ? and `till_date` is null or date(`till_date`) <= ?"

Comment: @Tintin I've updated my answer, can you give it a try to see if it works as expected?

Comment: It's omitting one record where  from_date is '2018-12-30 00:00:00' and till_date is '2019-01-02 00:00:00', do you have any idea why ?

Comment: Ok, I found a logical error in the SQL query that I posted in the question...  Let me fix it.

Comment: Do you have softdeletes for this table? If so, check the `deleted_at` column.

If not, can you post the executed query here?

Comment: I have solved the issue and posted the answer. Thanks! for you time.